# What is a efficient way/method to get data from row based on conditions and remove it if not necessary in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

I have an excel file which consists import/export products of the country and I would like to create a big database which consists all information from 2011 year. I am working with Pandas library to handle this project and during coding I stuck with one challenge.
Here is my dataframe looks like:

```
     TNVED                                       Product_Name  Export_Value  Impor_Value  Year Country       Region
0   010190           Лошади, ослы, мулы и лошаки живые прочие           0.0          1.3  2011          Акмолинская
2   010190                                             Россия           0.0          1.3  2011          Акмолинская
3   010190                                           Беларусь           0.0          0.0  2011          Акмолинская
4   010210  Чистопородный племенной крупный рогатый скот ж...           0.0        400.3  2011          Акмолинская
6   010210                                             Россия           0.0        400.3  2011          Акмолинская
7   010210                                           Беларусь           0.0          0.0  2011          Акмолинская
```

As you can see from this dataframe the first row consists name of the product and following rows are countries. I want to take country name and append it to column{Страна}. For example for the first entry:

**I want**

```
    TNVED                                       Product_Name  Export_Value  Impor_Value  Year Country       Region
0   010190           Лошади, ослы, мулы и лошаки живые прочие            0.0           1.3  2011        Россия    Акмолинская
```

**Example 2 I want**

```
    TNVED                                       Product_Name  Export_Value  Impor_Value  Year Country       Region
0   010190           Лошади, ослы, мулы и лошаки живые прочие            0.0           1.3  2011  Россия      Акмолинская
1   010210  Чистопородный племенной крупный рогатый скот ж...            0.0         400.3  2011  Россия      Акмолинская
```

**What I did**
I need to remove if the row if there is no transaction performed according to to the first column, if performed take the country name and append it to columnn{Страна} and remove the row.
Hope for your understanding.

Comment: Can you provide your columns in English?

Comment: To do this, there has to be somehow to distinguish the country and product rows, and find out how they relate to each other. Are they always in the form "ProductRow - CountryRow - ProductRow - CountryRow..."?

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen yeah, I thought about that, but this is the only data I have, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. In your example, what does Беларусь in row 3 refer to, for instance?

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen I believe that the responsible organisation which made this excel file just included countires within the export/import trade framework. If there is any export/import trades their put values, if none just 0. This is how I understood

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen I will try to drop rows where Export/Import column values are equal to 0